# I have problems when try to save records to the LocalDB

Tags: c#, dataset, localdb

I use VS 2012 and LocalDB for storing data.

This is my Solution Explorer:

[image]

I have one simple table in `TestDb`. Here is structure of that table:

[image]

I run the program and add some records to the table. And I use `BindingNavigator` and `DataGridView` for adding and displaying data.

[image]

But there are some problems.

1. When program starts it connects to the database very very slowly.
2. When I press `Save` button on the navigator it does not save records to the database table.

[image]

So, what are the problems? Why is connecting so slow and why does it not save records into the database?

Answer (score 0):

It should be about your DNS resolver. if localhost is missing from your reslove configuration. Windows has an analagous file somewhere in the System directory.

You can try changing "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in db connction parameters. It will probably work!

Comment: I can not find localhost. Where is it?

Comment: I dont how u use connectionString but did you check app.config in your project ?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalDbTest.Properties.Settings.TestDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDB.sdf" providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>